# How do I reference a different this in a javascript object literal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I reference a different this in a javascript object literal ? For example:

```
var Dispatcher = require('../dispatchers/dispatcher.js');

var App = React.createClass({

    handleEvent : function(item){
        //...
    },

    events : {
        dispatcherIndex: Dispatcher.register(function(payload) { //register a callback and set the result
           this.handleEvent(payload); //this 'this' is the wrong one since this is being called as a callback
           //how do i reference the right one (the one that has the handleEvent function)?
        })
    }
});
```

As you can see, we register a callback. Therefore, the 'this' reference in that callback isnt going to reference the object we want. How do we do this when we cant create a closure for 'this'?

Comment: Where do you want `this` to refer to? Anonymous object that `events` refers to? Anonymous object passed to a constructor? `App`?

Comment: @zerkms I want `this` to refer to the object which contains the `handleEvent` function.

Comment: [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: The `app` object is created using `React.createClass`. I'm curious to what this function is returning?

Comment: What you want can't be achieved. What is this `events` property anyway, I don't think it's part of the standard ReactJS API?

Comment: @FelixKling its not, its just my convention so that I separate what uses the events architecture and what mutates the object.

Comment: OK. You'd have to call `Dispatcher.register(...)` and store the index after the instance was constructed. That implies you register a callback for every instance. If you don't want that, you'd have to adjust `Dispatcher` so that it allows you to trigger the callback passed to `Dispatcher.register` with an arbitrary receiver (`this` value). But since we don't know how `Dispatcher` works, there is not much we can say about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module pattern and this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547918/module-pattern-and-this)