# Module pattern and this

Tags: javascript

I am using the module pattern for my JavaScript "classes". Is there any significant downside to declaring a `var self` outisde of the class I am returning and then setting it to `this` inside the class constructor so that I don't have to worry about the context switching when I don't want it to. In this small example it's probably unnecessary, this is just an example.

Example:

```
    var Seat = (function() {
      var self = null;
      function Seat(startX, startY, inputSeatNumber, inputTableNumber) {
        self = this;
        self.radius = 10;
        self.x = startX; self.y = startY;
        self.seatNumber = inputSeatNumber;
        self.tableNumber = inputTableNumber;
      }

      Seat.prototype.moveTo = function(newX, newY) {
        if(newX >= 0 && newY >= 0) {
          self.x = newX; self.y = newY;
        }
      };

      return Seat;
    })();
```

EDIT: example added

```
var SeatingChartView = (function() {
  function SeatingChartView(canvas_id, seatingChartController, seatForm) {
    this.stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas_id);
    this.controller = seatingChartController;
    this.seatForm = seatForm;

    this.disableRightClick(canvas_id);
  }

  SeatingChartView.prototype.render = function() {
    this.stage.update();
  }

  SeatingChartView.prototype.addSeat = function(newSeat) {
    var newCircle = new createjs.Shape();
    newCircle.graphics.beginFill("black").drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
    newCircle.x = newSeat.x;
    newCircle.y = newSeat.y;
    newCircle.seat = newSeat;
    newCircle.on('click', function(event) {
      if(event.nativeEvent.button == 2) {
        this.seatForm.open(event.currentTarget.seat);
      }
    });
    newCircle.on('pressmove', this.controller.moveSeat)
    this.stage.addChild(newCircle);
  }

  SeatingChartView.prototype.removeSeat = function(seat) {
    this.stage.children.forEach(function(child) {
      if(child.seat === seat) {
        this.stage.removeChild(child);
      }
    });
  }

  SeatingChartView.prototype.setBackground = function(imageLocation) {
    this.background = new createjs.Bitmap(imageLocation);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      this.stage.canvas.width = this.background.image.width;
      this.stage.canvas.height = this.background.image.height;
      this.stage.addChild(this.background);
      this.stage.update();
    }.bind(this), 500);
  }

  SeatingChartView.prototype.disableRightClick = function(canvas_id) {
    $(function() {
      $('#' + canvas_id).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
        return false;
      });
    });
  }

return SeatingChartView;
})();
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `self` - that keyword is already defined. If you're going to do something like this, I'd recommend `_self` or `_this` or something else that doesn't conflict.

Comment: Basically there is no perfect answer to address context switching. Most commonly people will use `var self = this` like in my answer. You cannot run away from it because it is encapsulation. And what you did was "deencapsulation". It is perfectly fine if you never meant to extend your class. Then again there are much simpler design patterns if your requirements are loose.

Answer (score 3):

In that case every new instance of `Seat` will share the newest `Self` object since it is set in the constructor. You should avoid doing this.

Comment: Is there a way to do prototypal inheritance and still maintain the this reference inside of Whatever.prototype.something function?

Comment: @ThomYorkkke Can you provide a sample where it doesn't automatically maintain the `this` reference while using the function on an instance of `Seat`?

Comment: @KevinB Yup, I just edited it and added. The problem is that if render or addSeat is called from the controller the this context now references the controller.

Comment: @ThomYorkkke doig prototypial inheritance in my answer will have all `this` reference `Seat`. But that is really not the main point. You will understand as you go...

Answer (score 3):

A more practical demo example might be something like this, where you want to make sure `this` is the instance of the class.

```
function Foo() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.someItem = {};

    _this.go = function() {
        doSomethingElse(function(result) {
            _this.someItem.something = result; // _this and this are different
        });
    };
};

function doSomethingElse(callback) {
    callback('asdf');
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.go();
```

For your example using that pattern, you can define the `_this` in each method if it would be any benefit (this one wouldn't, but a more complex example might):

```
Seat.prototype.moveTo = function(newX, newY) {
    var _this = this;
    if(newX >= 0 && newY >= 0) {
        _this.x = newX; _this.y = newY;
    }
};
```

Comment: There are ways to change "this" in different contexts to avoid all this, but personally I find this one easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by doing it this way, all instances of `Seat` will have the same `this`, causing problems all over the place. Just remove the `var self` and use `this` in all places where you were using `self`. In the code you've given, there's no point where you will lose reference to `this`.

*(@added example)* Now your question makes more sense.

Instead of trying to handle this for all methods at once, you'll have to handle it at each point where you're using a function that has a different `this` (any function that isn't on the prototype or instance).

If you don't need `this` inside the callback, I would just use `.bind` to make the instance `this` available inside. Note however that `.bind` isn't supported in some (very)old versions of IE, so you'll either need a polyfil to work for those, or store `this` in a var.

```
  SeatingChartView.prototype.addSeat = function(newSeat) {
    var newCircle = new createjs.Shape();
    newCircle.graphics.beginFill("black").drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
    newCircle.x = newSeat.x;
    newCircle.y = newSeat.y;
    newCircle.seat = newSeat;
    newCircle.on('click', function(event) {
      if(event.nativeEvent.button == 2) {
        this.seatForm.open(event.currentTarget.seat);
      }
    }.bind(this)); // modified here, added `.bind(this)`
    newCircle.on('pressmove', this.controller.moveSeat)
    this.stage.addChild(newCircle);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would totally negate the purpose of "classing". But in JS it's called prototyping.

Principally you want the base prototype to be "copied" when creating new instances. The base prototype should be shielded from changes when extended.

Suppose you have done what you did, all instances of `Seat` will have the same properties. Even worst, when creating new "copies" of `Seat`, all other previously created copies will have their values changed.

Since you want `this` to maintain reference to `Seat`, I would recommend using the following pattern:

```
var Base = {
    init: function(arg) {
        this.name = arg;
    },
    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
Base.init('foo');
Base.getName(); // returns 'foo'
```

Your transformed code:

```
var Seat = {
    init: function(startX, startY, inputSeatNumber, inputTableNumber) {
        this.radius = 10;
        this.x = startX; 
        this.y = startY;
        this.seatNumber = inputSeatNumber;
        this.tableNumber = inputTableNumber;
    },
    moveTo: function(newX, newY) {
        if (newX >= 0 && newY >= 0) {
            this.x = newX; this.y = newY;
        }
    },
    setBackground: function(imageLocation) {
        var self = this;
        this.background = new createjs.Bitmap(imageLocation);
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.stage.canvas.width = self.background.image.width;
            self.stage.canvas.height = self.background.image.height;
            self.stage.addChild(self.background);
            self.stage.update();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Extend the prototype:

```
var vipSeat = Object.create(Seat);
vipSeat.init( //your init values )
```

You can also not create an init method and simply use Object.create's second argument to assignment initial values to the prototype: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Example:_Using_propertiesObject_argument_with_Object.create